# How to encode xml data

Tags: url-encoding, nsmutableurlrequest

In my app i have to send a xml data as request, I am creating the xml string like this

```
    NSString* str = @"<Item><Name>";
str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:string1];
str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@"</Name><Description>"];
str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:string2];
str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@"</Description><Rate>"];
str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:string3];
str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@"</Rate></Item>"];
```

after that i am creating a URLString.

```
   NSString* curl = @"url?";
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:@"string"];
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:@"&apikey=@"value"&searchtext="];
curl = [curl stringByAppendingString:[aString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Than i am creating NSURL by passing the string
 NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:curl];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL 
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:10];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

But i am not getting the result

Is encoding the xml string is correct?

Can any one help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen?

http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML

Comment: I saw it but i cannot find how to get it